# Mounted Volume can't be opened with Finder, opening it with the terminal resolves everything

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, file-sharing, volumes

We got a strange problem.
We have declared in the /etc/fstab to mount a volume. At first everything seems to work. But now we face this:

If you go to the mounted Volume in the finder (/Network/shared) it won't open the folder and says that you don't have sufficient rights to open it (in fstab the user + password is declared and the password isn't changed).

But if we open the terminal and do this:

```
ls /Network/Shared    
cd /Network/Shared
```

He gives the output of all the folder and files located in the shared folder. And he can access the folder.

If we open the terminal and do:

```
open /Network/Shared
```

He opens the Volume, if we close it and we go to /Network/Shared the volume is accessible, but earlier he couldn't open it. Do you guys know why this happens? And how we can resolve it. Because I can't tell the customer if the shared Volume isn't accessible in the finder that he needs to open the terminal and open it from here.

Answer (score 0):

In Mail.app or Safari and OS X Lion, when you click on a URL in the form smb://myserver.mydomain.com/Sharepoint/Folder1/Folder2 to connect to the SMB server myserver.mydomain.com, the volume that mounts on your desktop will be different than in previous versions of Mac OS X.

In OS X Lion and later, the Finder will mount the volume named Sharepoint on the SMB server myserver.mydomain.com, and open a window showing the contents of the directory named Folder2. Note: You must have permission to read Sharepoint, Folder1, and all other directories in the path to Folder2. Otherwise you will see the message "The folder can't be opened because you don't have permission to see its contents."

In Mac OS X v10.6 and earlier, the Finder will mount the folder named Folder2 and open a window showing its contents. You only need permissions to read Folder2 in order to mount it.
Additional Information

In OS X Lion and later, the "mount_smbfs" command can be used in a Terminal window or a shell script to replicate the Finder behavior in Mac OS X v10.6 and earlier. For more information, type the following command in a Terminal window:

man mount_smbfs

Further details can be found here: http://infoapple.com.br